# Inconsistent results from std::regex_search with gcc 4.9.1

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, c++11

I'm getting various wrong results from std::regex_search, seemingly depending on other code in the program:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  std::smatch res;

  std::regex_search(std::string("fooquxbarquack"),res,std::regex("foo(?=qux)(.*)ar"));
  std::cout<<res[0]<<std::endl;

  std::regex_search(std::string("foofofowoof"),res,std::regex("(o.){4}"));
  std::cout<<res[0]<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output (formatted as c strings):

```
fooquxba0\n
ofofow\xB0\x00\n
```

If I reverse the tests, the output becomes:

```
ofofow\xD0\x00\n
fooquxbar\n
```

And with other arrangements of the code, it sometimes produces the expected output (`fooquxbar` and `ofofowoo`).

gcc version:

```
$ ../bin/gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=../bin/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/compilers/gcc_r/4.9.1rh62/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: /free/tmp/gccwork/gcc-4.9.1//configure --prefix=/compilers/gcc_r/4.9.1rh62/
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.1 (GCC)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call `regex_search` or `regex_match` overloads taking a `match_results` with a temporary `std::string`. (Well, you can, pre-C++14, but you can't do anything useful with the result.)

These functions populate the `match_results` with iterators into the string you passed, but if you pass a temporary `std::string`, then the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full expression, and the iterators are invalidated. When you later attempt to use `res[0]`, undefined behavior results.

This is why in C++14 [LWG issue 2329](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2329) added explicitly deleted overloads to prevent them from being called with a temporary. It looks like  libstdc++ hasn't implemented this yet. Your code doesn't compile with clang and libc++ in C++14 mode.